# Have an element always at the same position with window resizes

Tags: css, position

I have the following testpage: ***

With a resolution of 1920x1080 the icon bar is located above the purple line.
On any other resolution it isn't anymore.
What is the best way to accomplish this (without javascript if possible)?

While I also would love to have the div element scale automatically, this is only the second problem. The main issue would be to have it always at the specific position.
As you can see % doesn't work.

```
#icons {
position: absolute;
right: 11%;
bottom: 12%;
width: auto;
height: auto;

z-index: 8;
max-width: 60%;
}
```

Do I have to work with "rem" or something along those lines (didn't work when I tried it either)? Is there even a way to do this?
Having an element in the top left corner obviously is very easy, since it will always stay the same even when resizing.
With this position there's also the problem of extra toolbars or similar - the position changes as soon as you hide the toolbar of the browser for example.
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is absolutely positioned to the right and bottom edges of the window, so the solution is to position the background there too. Change `top center` to `bottom right`.

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, "Myriad Pro";
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #202020 url(img/body_back.jpg) no-repeat bottom right fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: easy but working solution, thanks! is there a way now to really resize the content of the #icons div (one image) accordingly to the resize of the browser? if i use e.g. max-width: 60% it only resizes when the browser is really small. it should resize just so it always stays in the exact same spot?

Comment: No, sorry, I can't seem to think of a way to keep the div in the same position when it gets smaller. You'd need a `min-right` property or something, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought of trying:

```
#icons {
  position: fixed;
  right: 11%;
  bottom: 12%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 8;
  max-width: 60%;
}
```

I use `fixed` for stuff I want to stay on the same spot, it usually "fixes" it to stay in its set place.

Comment: well, i think the main issue is the background image (what mr lister wrote), thanks for the reply!

Comment: no problem I see what you mean because the background is adjusting not the icons.